# CQ5: disable an ObservationListener during package upload

Tags: aem

I have an ObservationListener that does a few things when an author adds/deletes components from a parsys in /content. The problem I'm running into is that the same events I'm listening to, fire whenever a package is installed (and that can get costly). I would like a way to either edit the package manager workflow to disable my service, install the package, then renable the service when the package is finished, or differentiate a package install from a node being edited and ignore them in my listener.

Alternatively, I'm curious if there is an import/install queue of some sort that I could watch so --- if my event is fired and the queue is full/still has items to install, wait until the queue is empty, then continue on with my event handling.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Sling or CQ provide events to let you know when things are about to be installed.

If it's JCR events that you are listening to, you might use Event.getUserID() to find out who's changing content and differentiate between admin (or whichever user is used to install content packages) and regular users. But note that if you later switch to an Oak-based content repository there are some limitations with this, see http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/differences.html